# Possible to inject a new menu into a program's menu bar?

Tags: ida, windows, debugging, pe, injection

Is it be possible to inject a new menu/menu item into a program's menu bar?

As an example, in Notepad's (Windows) "Help" menu, would it be possible to add a new entry to that menu like "Open calculator" which runs calc.exe when clicked? How would one accomplish something like this?